# Use a variable in an attribute constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, models

Is it possible to use a variable in an attribute constructor, something like this below:

```
[Foo(bar)]
public string Baz { get; set; }
```

Comment: where is situated the `myVar` value? Is it another property or an attribute?

Comment: Short answer is no (attributes add metadata and are evaluated a compile-time so therefore must be constants)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is valid, but it contains references to irrelevant context. It should really be written like so:

---

Is it possible to use a variable in an attribute constructor, something like this below:

```
[Foo(bar)]
public string Baz { get; set; }
```

---

The answer, as Stephen Muecke says, is no.

> attributes add metadata and are evaluated a compile-time so therefore must be constants

Comment: Naughty Ninja, I would edit the question, otherwise it seems like people are going to close it.